# How to prepare the T4's environment to use SQLite?

Tags: t4, system.data.sqlite

I am having a hard time to properly set up the environment for T4 to recognize the Sqlite provider.  Steps I have taken:

1. Add assemblies and imports to in .tt

   <#@ assembly name="\System.Data.SQLite.dll" #>
   <#@ import namespace="System.Data.SQLite" #>
2. At the beginning of tt, add SQLite as one of the providers.

   // add sqlite
    try
    {
       var dataSet = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.data") as System.Data.DataSet;
       dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add("SQLite Data Provider"
       , ".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
       , "System.Data.SQLite"
       , "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite");
   }
   catch (System.Data.ConstraintException) { }

I verified in SQLite is one of the providers in DbProviderFactories.

This didn't get SQLite to load by T4.  Under a normal application, a SQLite entry would be added to the App.config section.  SQLite somehow preloads a native dll.  I suspect the preloading is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I resolved the problem by installing System.Data.Sqlite.  The installer puts the library in the GAC.  The additional code above is not necessary.  I was trying to avoid the GAC, but didn't find another way out.